# Wait until all data is loaded from Webpage in HTTPoison

Tags: elixir, httpoison

I'm trying to load a webpage, where the data I'm interested in is loaded via `Ajax` after the initial page load. When I fetch the page, the text I currently see is `Loading records...`.

I'm wondering what techniques I can use to wait until that section has loaded before the data is returned to me.

Currently I'm using the Elixir `HTTPoison` library, but am open to different techniques in Elixir/Erlang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libraries like `HTTPoison` only make the initial web request, returning the "server-rendered" content. They don't process the client-side code and markup. You need a headless browser / web-driver like `PhantomJS`, to actually process it and execute the javascript code (similar to how a normal web browser does).

**Two popular Elixir libraries that do the job**, (though they are mostly used for integration testing), are:

- [`Hound`](https://github.com/HashNuke/hound)
- [`Wallaby`](https://github.com/keathley/wallaby)

---

If the Ajax call is simple enough, another option is to first load the webpage and the scripts using `HTTPoison`, then extract the Javascript code using something like [`Floki`](https://github.com/philss/floki), parse the Ajax call being made and then perform it manually via `HTTPoison`.